# How to change the checkBox text? tried to change it in the design but getting warning and the text is not changing. using android studio kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I changed the text to Milliseconds but when running the application the text is still CheckBox.

[image: checkbox text]

the activity_main.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="355dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.49"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:text="Milliseconds"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/seekBar" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: check your activity file.

Answer (score 0):

In the `activity_main.xml` side everything is fine, kindly check with your class file maybe you set it like below

```
val myCheckBox = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.myCheckBox)

myCheckBox.text = "CheckBox"
```

that's why you getting CheckBox text in your application.

Comment: The solution was to add this line to strings.xml <string name="milliseconds">Milliseconds</string> and then to change in the activity_main.xml to this line: android:text="@string/milliseconds" not sure why but this is working.